# AssociatedObject Binding Source is null while changing wpf binding property dynamically within a behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to create a style for textbox in a resource file, in which I want to set the NotifyOnError property of the each textbox to true.

I am using a behavior for the same, but I am not able to do that,

Code which I already tried is :

```
BindingExpression be = this.AssociatedObject.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);

if (be!=null)
{
    Binding b = be.ParentBinding;
    Binding newBinding = new Binding()
                                {
                                    Source = b.Source,
                                    Path = b.Path,
                                    Mode = b.Mode,
                                    NotifyOnValidationError = true
                                };
    BindingOperations.ClearBinding(this.AssociatedObject, TextBox.TextProperty);
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.AssociatedObject, TextBox.TextProperty, newBinding);

    BindingExpression bex = this.AssociatedObject.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
    if (bex != null)
    {
        bex.UpdateTarget();
    }   
}
```

But unfortunately I don't see any values in the textboxes now. When I debugged it, I found that Source property is null, while copying it from the old binding (refer the code above)

P.S. I am fine with getting that working in xaml as well, if someone can give me a solution.

Comment: I forgot to mention that, binding is already been set for each textbox in individual xaml files. What I am trying to do is that, I want to make sure that NotifyOnValidationError is set to true, if it is not already set in binding.

Comment: Is `newXPath` a valid property on `oldBinding.Source`? I suspect not. You probably need to set `newBinding.Path = oldBinding.Path` so it binds to the same property, or better yet just change the `NotifyOnValidationError` and `ValidatesOnExceptions` properties of the existing binding to `true`

Comment: Ok, I tried first option which you told, have set path property to the oldBinding. Still not showing up the values in textboxes.
Second option is not allowed, I get and error that can't change the existing binding when it is already set.